# Number of integer solutions for a linear equation where some of the coefficients are negative integers.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I already know the combinations way for calculating the number of **non-negative integer** solutions where coefficients of the linear equation are all **positive integers**.

So my question breaks down into two parts:

1- How do we put into consideration the negative solutions? hence putting into account all possible integer solutions. can we apply some transformation or something? give me hints.

2- How to deal with negative integer coefficients in the linear equation?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking. Perhaps an example equation or a more precise formulation?

Comment: You are interested in Linear Diophantine Equations (which is a keyword for what you should search for if you want to know more). These equations have either zero or infinitely many solutions, so counting the number of solutions isn't as interesting. However, solving them is.

Comment: @RandyMarsh So it's proved they can never have finite number of solutions?

Comment: You are looking for solutions $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ to an equation of the form 
$$
a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b, 
$$
where $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, yeah?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes!!

Comment: @AmirWG They can have a finite number of solutions, and there is only one case: when they have 0 solutions. Otherwise, if a solution exists, it can be used to generate infinitely many solutions. For example, if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a solution to $ax+by+cz=n$ then $(x_0 - by_0,y_0+ay_0,z_0)$ is also a solution. But so is $(x_0 - k\cdot by_0,y_0+k\cdot ay_0,z_0)$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: @RandyMarsh, But that's not necessarily true for a system of Linear Diophantine Equations, right?

Comment: @AmirWG This paper https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf addresses most of you questions.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for solutions $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ to a [linear Diophantine equation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations) of the form
$$
a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b, 
$$
where $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$.

For $n=1$, i.e. $ax = b$, we either have a single solution $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ that is already a positive integer or we don't depending on whether $a \mid b$ or not.

For $n \geq 2$, either there are no solutions or there are (countably) infinitely many solutions. For example, with $n = 2$, the equation
$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 = b$ has integer solutions if and only if
$d = \gcd(a_1, a_2)$ divides $b$. This is a famous problem solved by [Bézout's identity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), with all solutions of the form
$$
(x_1, x_2) = \biggl( X_1 - \frac{ka_2}{d},\, X_2 + \frac{ka_1}{d} \biggr), 
$$
where $(X_1, X_2) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ is a solution, found say by the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. As you allude to, some finite number of these (countably) infinitely many solutions may be in the first quadrant.

---

For example, the equation $2x_1 + 3x_2 = 1$ has solutions of the form
$$
(2 - 3k, -1 + 2k)
$$
but none of them happen to land in the first quadrant (in the figure, each solution is labeled by the index $k$):

[image: Solutions to linear Diophantine equation in two variables.]

Comment: Amazing, what about a system of linear diophantite equations with n = 2. can we still solve it using bezouts identity. if yes, how so?

Comment: Sure, once you find the family of solutions to one equation, parametrized by $k$, plug in those coordinates into the second equation. This will yield an equation in the variable $k$ which may or may not have an integer solution. Essentially, by including a second equation, you're looking at another line in the figure, which may or may not cross the initial line at one of the lattice points.

Comment: Or you can use the sophisticated machinery of linear algebra over the integers (everything's more difficult than the usual linear algebra you're used to that works over a field). There we have tools like Smith normal form or Hermite normal form [to solve linear systems](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations).

Comment: Thanks alot, that was very helpful.